# Getting the name of the development machine at compile time?

Tags: ios, xcode, build-process

I'm building an iOS app that communicates with a server. We have a test / staging server, a production server and each dev has a local instance of the server for development.

I've added some simple logic which configures the address of the server depending on whether we're running a TestFlight build, an App Store build or a debug build (for development). For the development build, the app tries to hit localhost, which is all well and good if we're running on the Simulator, but not so great if we're running on device.

I'm aware of ngrok, which is a possible solution, but since the exposed URL is partially randomly generated (for the free version at least), it's not a great fit. I was thinking that a workable approach for development could be to check the name of the development machine at compile time and insert this value. But I'm not sure how to achieve this, if it's possible at all. I remember doing compile time variable filtering using ant / maven and environment property files back in my Java days, but I'm wondering if there's a fairly straightforward way to achieve this in Xcode.

Can anybody shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

So I carried on digging, and went with the following solution. Elements of this have been touched upon in numerous other posts here.

1. I added a new header file called HostNameMacroHeader.h to my
   project.
2. I added a 'Run Script' phase to my build, *before the
       'Compile Sources'phase*. The script contains the following:

   ```
   echo "//***AUTOGENERATED FILE***" > ${SRCROOT}/MyAppName/HostNameMacroHeader.h 
   echo "#define BUILD_HOST_NAME @\"`hostname`\"" >> ${SRCROOT}/MyAppName/HostNameMacroHeader.h
   ```

Then in my implementation, where I want to use the server address, I use the generated BUILD_HOST_NAME macro.

It's a somewhat hacky solution, but it does the job for now. Suggestions and cleaner versions are welcome.